# How to upload an .ipa file to iTunes Connect from Windows

Tags: ios, windows, ipa

I've made an iPhone app and have a .ipa file containing the app binaries ready to upload.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to upload the .ipa file to iTunes Connect from Windows.

Is this possible, or will I need to upload from a macOS system?

Comment: You can use our cloud ApplicationLoader for uploading IPA files from any machine including Windows: https://wenz.io/ApplicationLoader Disclaimer: I'm the creator of the site.

Comment: @SteffenWenz While the question is currently closed, if it gets reopened this would be more appropriate as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Unfortunately, you need macOS to do this. Read [Submitting Your App to the Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html) and follow the steps while using macOS.

Comment: This is certainly not true for Linux, where you can use ideviceinstaller. I would imagine there's a similar approach for Windows.

Comment: Also for nativescript you can use their command line tool to publish a built IPA, I don't see why it wouldn't work for a IPA that was built through some other method. I think the way it works is they send the IPA to their servers and proxy it to itunes through a mac computer.

https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/publishing/publish-ios

Answer (score 15):

I was faced with the same problem when needing to upload an app from Windows. To solve it, I developed a cross-platform application. It is written in Node.js and works by mimicking the functionality of the Application Loader software in macOS.

It is available here: https://github.com/simonnilsson/ios-uploader

If you install it and have your .ipa file available it can be as simple as this to upload:

```
$ ios-uploader -u <username> -p <password> -f <path/to/app.ipa>
```

Answer (score 3):

I use a Windows to submit all my Mac apps. I build it using phonegap and then I use a Virtual Mac OS X with Oracle VM Virtual Box for this.

Comment: So you don't really use Windows to do it; you use macOS.